# phpdocx - generating word documents via phpdocx library

Tags: php, docx, phpdocx

I am in need of making files dynamically in editable word form from php and mysql. I found good library PHPdocx and it works for now, but it saves output file to the server. 
All I want  to open word document file from web serwer on my browser window. First I tried:

> header("Location: example_text.docx");

Unfortunatelly it doesnt work because it is still opened in php file instead of docx. Then I found a better way:

```
echo "
<script>
    window.location.replace('example_text.docx')
</script>
";
```

It works fine but still doesnt satisfy me - It opens a standard browser window with a question - open or save file to local hard disk. I want to automatically see generated file, and than decide if i want to save it to local hard drive. Is there a way to do this?
I guess it is matter of browser preferences but not sure. Please advice.

Comment: you cant save it to to the users computer with asking them first.

Comment: i dont want to save it without asking. i want to open word file in the same browser window as i started php script that creates dynamically word file.

Comment: browsers can't read the word file format.

Comment: i can read for example pdf.. cant i do the same with word files?

Comment: your browser doesn't read the pdf, the adobe (or alternative) plug-in does

Comment: are there any to read word docx?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using COM , but it is not browser-compliant.
However try this way.

```
header('Content-disposition: inline');
header('Content-type: application/msword');
readfile('yourwordfile.doc');
exit;
```